# How to create a Hash if keys and values are separately provided?

Tags: ruby

If keys and values are separately provided how can I make a Hash?
I'm doing it now like this.

```
h = Hash.new
values.each_with_index do |v, i|
  h[keys[i]] = v
end
```

But I think there is a better way to do it. Any suggestion?

Comment: I would do it as @Arup suggests, using `zip`, but you could make your code work with a slight modification: `keys.size.times {|i| h[keys[i]] = values[i]}`. I assume you know you can write `h = Hash.new` as `h = {}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do as below :

Using [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) :

```
Hash[keys.zip(values)]
```

or using Ruby2.1.0 [`Array#to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) :

```
keys.zip(values).to_h
```